# MVC Http PUT not working

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

when using HTTP post to update my **times** record for example it works, but when i use put it doesn't. 
I have read some articles about CRUD and HTTP methods, and as known HTTP PUT is  for the update part, is it only for WEB API or can i use it in my .net mvc project and im doing something wrong? Here's my code

```
var times = GetTimes(); // times array object

var enrollmentId = $('#EnrolledSubject').data('id');

$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: "/Subjects/UpdateTimes?enrollmentId="+enrollmentId,
    type: "PUT",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'times': times}),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        console.log('error ' + y);

        OnAJAXError(x, y, z);
    }
});
```

and MVC controller Subjects

```
[Route("UpdateTimes")]
[HttpPut]
public bool UpdateTimes(List<Time> times)
{
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Using .NET core?

Comment: Try taking out the JSON.stringify() method. I have had issues with this in the past where I serialize my JSON to a string and the server expects JSON so it does not read my call because it thinks it is getting a string. You can test this by rewriting your method so it takes a string instead of a list obj.

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.2 web application

Comment: I am going to write a quick script for you to test. May I get an example of what the Time model looks like?

Comment: I've tried string and dynamic instead of my object, still 404 not found.

Comment: but using POST method it works.

Comment: times[0] = {
            Day: obj.dataset.dayNb,
            Period: obj.dataset.periodCode,
            Room: obj.dataset.room,
            ViewOnSchedual: obj.dataset.view
        };

Comment: That's good! Let see if we can get the PUT working though.

Comment: @thisextendsthat I tried removing the query string , same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be coming from your iis configuration. You could try adding this  in your web.config :

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The c# code did not change for me so you can leave yours as is.

As far as the aJax call,

remove dataType, contentType, and the JSON.stringify(). Mine is below.

I did create a Time Model from what you gave me. I hope I got the datatypes correct

```
public class Time
{
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Room { get; set; }
    public bool ViewOnSchedual { get; set; }
}
```

The javascript:

```
    function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    }

    function GetTimes() {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 10; i--;) {
            var d = new Date();
            arr.push({
                Day: getRandomInt(365),
                Period: "abc_" + i,
                Room: "room_" + i,
                ViewOnSchedual: (i % 2 === 0) ? true : false
            })
        }
        return arr;
    }
    $("#put_time").off().on("click", function () {
        var times = GetTimes();  
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/UpdateTimes",
            type: "PUT",
            data: {"times": times},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success")
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                console.error("there was an error")
                console.log(x, y, z)
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: thanks christian, turns out the issue was from the iis config .